# FCM notification problem with Chunk in PHP

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification all of my users. My user almost 5000 so I chunk my array like bellow:

```
$value = array_chunk($userList,1000,true);
```

And this my CURL function field:

```
$messageArray = array();
$messageArray["notification"] = array (
    'title' => $title,
    'message' => $msg,
    'customParam' => $customParam,
);
if (count($tokens)  ==  1){

    $fields = array(
        'to' => $tokens[0],
        'data' => $messageArray,
    );
}
elseif(count($tokens) > 1)
{
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $tokens,
        'data' => $messageArray,
    );
}
```

its showing error when second looping :
"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array

my loop :

```
foreach ($userList as $val)
{
    $db->sendPushCustom($val,$title,$msg,$customParam);
}
```

Full error

```
{"multicast_id":9010611916348765550,"success":34,"failure":966,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534860356%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534860831%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534862321%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534864995%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534863615%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1613388534863232%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534865359%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534920954%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534863979%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1613388534867380%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534867898%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534870059%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534869891%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534881022%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534882968%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534882303%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534882320%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534886304%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534886136%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534892516%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534888043%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534894917%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534894924%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534896284%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534896285%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534910245%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534908689%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534910608%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534909160%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534909908%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534910235%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534921318%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534912700%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"message_id":"0:1613388534913329%e4dff2acf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}"registration_ids"
field is not a JSON array
"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array
"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array
"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array`
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome. It is not clear what you are asking, can you have another try

Comment: On the First loop its just sending notification to 33 users
its showing error when second looping :
"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array

Comment: But there are no Loops in the code you show us?

Comment: sorry for that i have added my loop function into the post. Can you please check ?

Comment: Have you shown us the COMPLETE Error message? That looks like a summary to me

Comment: @RiggsFolly you can check now